# Remove Negatively voted Questions?

Tags: discussion

Should negatively voted questions be removed from MO in order to keep it 'clean', or, put differently: what is the use of negatively voted questions on MO?

I am especially interested in opinions on removing own questions that have been downvoted, never upvoted and, never received any comment indicating that someone is interested in the topic?

Comment: This happens automatically. Negatively voted questions without any [upvoted] answers are eventually deleted.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for the clarification, but is it OK to pull the 'emergency break' myself, because I feel I couldn't get an idea across?

Comment: There is some argument for leaving the negative questions.  For example: new users will be able to see that this sort of question is discouraged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions which fulfil certain criteria such as having low score, no answers, few comments, few views, being closed etc. are automatically removed after a certain time. For details see
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

As to deleting a question of yours yourself, you can do so, but I suggest to do it not too
often. Also I suggest you to take into consideration that people may already be working on
writing a good answer for you, and may not like it to see your question disappearing 
immediately before they are done. To minimize these concerns, you may either delete your
question very quickly (say after a few minutes, i.e. before anybody may have put significant time into thinking about an answer), or wait at least a couple of days -- but these considerations depend quite a bit on the particular case.